# How Can i know if a string is on MD5 format

Tags: vb.net, md5

I want to check if a string is on md5 format in vb.net. I have found something similar on php but i do not know if this is possible in .net Does anyone of you know how to do this ?

Comment: if it is possible in php then same goes to vb. Use regex perhaps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

option 1:

```
Dim reg = New RegularExpressions.Regex("[0-9a-f]{32}", RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Compiled)
Function LooksMd5(str As String) As Boolean
    Return reg.IsMatch(str)
End Function
```

option2 (check and get bytes in one step - try parse string to bytes array)

```
Function TryParseHex32(str As String, ByRef result As Byte()) As Boolean
    If str.Length <> 32 Then Return False

    ReDim result(16)

    For i = 0 To 16
        Try
            result(i) = Convert.ToByte(str.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16)
            'or result(i) = Byte.Parse(str.Substring(i * 2, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)
        Catch ex As Exception
            result = Nothing
            Return False
        End Try
    Next
    Return True
End Function
```